# Does Maven support negative lookbehind regex in <packagingExcludes/>

Tags: java, regex, maven

I have the following regex:

```
.*(?<!min)(\.css)
```

Which is meant to match all CSS files which are not minified. This regex works when testing it on a [Java regex tester](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/). However, it does not work when using it with Maven WAR plugin's `<packagingExcludes/>` configuration parameter. I use it as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>    
        <packagingExcludes>
            <![CDATA[
            %regex[.*(?<!min)(\.css)]
             ]]>
        </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Does Maven WAR plugin support negative lookbehind regex? If so, how do I use it.

Comment: Inside packagingExcludes, why do you use **negative** lookaround ?  Try `.*min\.css`

Comment: That will match all CSS files which are minified `.min.css` rather than the other way around. I only want to exclude the `.css` without the `.min` part.

Comment: When I use `packageIncludes` it excludes everything that doesn't match the `packageIncludes` regex, so I am left with a web archive with only minified CSS files.

Comment: I even tried a `packageExcludes` matching all `.css` files and then a `packageIncludes` matching `.min.css` but the `packageIncludes` just removed everything that doesn't match it again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need CDATA. Use this:

```
<packagingExcludes>
%regex[.*(?&lt;!min)(\.css)]>
</packagingExcludes>


'&lt;' is equal to the sign '<'
```

Comment: I added `\.` before the min to test `*.min.js` or css : `.*(?<!\.min)(\.(css|js))`

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid it by naming your CSS files without any `.` characters in *except* for the extension pieces (`.css` or `.min.css`) then you don't need a negative lookbehind; this will do:

```
^[^.]+\.css$
```

(I can't remember if the anchors are needed. I've put them in.)

Otherwise, whether negative lookbehind is supported depends on the RE library used. Java's built-in one *does* support that feature (as it is PCRE-derived), but some others don't. Given that Java's does support it, there's at least a reasonable chance that it will work.

Enough to be worth just trying instead of putting effort into guessing about it ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer, which I deleted, was wrong.

The actual problem is that you have one closing bracket too much in your XML. On the last line you only need two closing brackets instead of three (`]]>` instead of `]]]>`)

This works fine when it test it on my computer:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>
<![CDATA[
%regex[.*(?<!min)(\.css)]
]]>
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm using `Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-03-01 01:31:09+0800)` and the plugin version `2.4`. I tried with both jdk1.6.0_65 and with the jdk1.8 beta and get the same results with both. I get the same result with the plugin declaration that you updated in your question above.

I have a almost empty war project with just two files in the `src/main/webapp` folder: `my.css` and `my-min.css`.

The command I run is `mvn clean install &&  jar tvf target/testweb-0.1.war` (project and artifactID is called `testweb`)

The output is:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
my-min.css
WEB-INF/web.xml
META-INF/maven/testweb/testweb/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/testweb/testweb/pom.properties
```

So it excludes `my.css` but it includes `my-min.css`.

What does your project structure look like?

Comment: The missing ']' was actually a typo in the question. What version of Maven are you using? Can you confirm that all .css files are removed except for .min.css files and that all normal non-css files remain?

Comment: Using plugin version 2.4 and maven 3.0.something, will check when I get back home. What are you using? What does your plugin declaration look like?

Comment: Updated my answer. Are you always doing a clean build? How do you check that the war file includes the files you want?

Comment: Yep, always doing a clean build, and I check by opening up the WAR file. Try this: try put in another file, such as a java class or image. Thanks for you time, by the way.